# ajax https request jsonp success callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im run this script on my http site, on network tab show what request 200 ok,
but success callback not runing

```
$.ajax({

  url: 'https://seobudget.ru',
  success: function(data){

     alert("123")
  },
crossDomain:true,
dataType:"jsonp"
});
```

im try remove "crossDomain:true" but its nothing change

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({

  url: 'https://seobudget.ru',
  dataType:"jsonp",
  success: function(data){
     alert("123")
  }

});
```

you put `dataType` in wrong place

Comment: use `complete` instead of `success` because you response isnt `success`

Comment: why? how do what it will be success?

Comment: take this url as an example: 'http://api.fanfou.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?id=fanfou'

Comment: If you haven't already, use `console.log(data)` within the success function and view the error message in your browser console.

Comment: im run code in console, but alert('123') not runing

Comment: did you have jquery exposed in your console? it seems that you have to read more about JavaScript